# Is it possible to switch template partial based on hash value in Mustache?

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

Ok, so I'm trying to get a grip on Mustache.js for rendering views in javascript. I have an API that returns a number of "events", which can be a number of different types. I want to render the events in (very) different ways, based on their type:

```
data : { 
  events: [ {title: 'hello', type: 'message'}, {title: 'world', type: 'image'} ] }
```

Ideally, I could do something like this:

```
{{#events}}
    {{#message}}
         <div class="message">{{title}}</div>
    {{/message}}
    {{#image}}
         <span>{{title}}</span>
    {{/image}}
{{/events}}
```

But that would (right?) force me to refactor my data into:

```
data : { 
  events: [ {message: {title: 'hello'}}, {image: {title: 'world'}} ] }
```

Is there a better way of solving this, without refactoring my data? Or should I just bite the bullet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mustache is logic-less so there's not much you can do with pure template code other than switching to [Handlebars](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/).

Your Mustache-friendly alternative would be to declare a helper and use it to select which template to render. It gets a little convoluted but you can avoid switching away from Mustache if that's something you can't change:

```
var base_template = '{{#events}}' +
                        '{{{event_renderer}}}' +
                    '{{/events}}';
var message_template = '<div>message: {{title}}</div>';
var image_template = '<div>image: {{title}}</div>';
var data = { 
  events: [ {title: 'hello', type: 'message'}, {title: 'world', type: 'image'} ],
  event_renderer: function() {
      return Mustache.render('{{> ' + this.type  + '}}', this, {message: message_template, image: image_template});
  }
}

Mustache.render(base_template, data);
```

The trick here is that you create a base template that will be the iterator, and pass in `event_renderer` as a helper. That helper will in turn call Mustache.render again, using partials to render each type of event you can have (that's the {{> partial}} notation).

The only ugly part here is that you need to add this `event_renderer` member to your JSON data, but other than that, it should all be fine (in Handlebars you could declare it as a helper and there's no need to merge it with your data).

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but would you mind giving me some input here? I'm looking for a simple tempting system, but at the moment I'm free to go either way – the API is still being built, and none of the actual GUI parts are built yet. Would you recommend going with Handlebars over Mustache? Or another library all together?

Comment: For this particular example, the difference will be that you can globally register your `event_renderer` helper with `Handlebars.registerHelper` and avoid having to mix-in this function every time you have some new data to render. In short, there's no syntax either on Handlebars that you can use to render one or the other partial based on the value of one of your members, you can only test for truthy and falsy values.